# With NAudio howto capture an signal played

Tags: .net, audio, naudio

Is there any way to capture a sound signal being played (by another application) in .NET (with or without the NAudio library)?

What I want to do is build an graphical visualization of the sounds played (like there are plenty apps), but without playing the sound itself (which seems non existing), but just by capturing the sound played already on the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With NAudio, you can use `WasapiLoopbackCapture` to capture the soundcard output. Unfortunately, there is no way to specifically capture the audio from another application though.